# Label transition is undone when text field gets disabled

Tags: css, disabled-input

I am creating a material like text field, and it works except for when I disable the input field. When the field is focused on, the label rises above the cursor if there's any input in the text box it should stay above the cursor. When I disable the textbox the label goes back to its original position even if there is text in the box ([See the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9gvzeakf/)).

Here is what I am doing:

```
.txt-group label {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    color: #999999;
}

.txt-group input:focus ~ label,
.txt-group input:valid ~ label,
.txt-group input:valid:disabled ~ label {
    top: -8px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: JavaScript may be needed for this solution. As far as I know, `:valid` is the only way to test in CSS if an `input` has content, but it ceases to pass if the element has the `readonly` or `disabled` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

When you are declaring the `disabled` css, you shouldn't need the `valid` selector as well.

Try This:

```
.txt-group input:focus ~ label,
.txt-group input:valid ~ label,
.txt-group input:disabled ~ label {
  top: -8px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Working **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9gvzeakf/1/)**

Comment: This method shifts the label up to the "completed" state, even if the disabled `input` field is empty.

Comment: @JonUleis Oh shit, you're right. My mistake! I just texted for if it had text in it.